# Comparar elementos de un array_keys PHP

Tags: php, java, jquery

Estoy armando algo para matemáticas y les comento que tengo que permitir que un usuario ingrese una cantidad finita de pares ordenados pertenecientes a una relación binaria definida sobre un conjunto finito.

Luego, tengo que determinar si la relación es reflexiva (que los elementos del conjunto estén en los pares, por ejemplo si está el numero 1, tiene que estar el par (1,1) y así con todos). Esta parte creo que ya la puedo hacer funcionar mediante un código que reciclé sacado de esta página.

La otra característica que debo cumplir es determinar si la relación es simétrica ( por ejemplo, si existe el par (1,4), debe existir el par (4,1) ). Esta ultima parte me cuesta porque no sé como comparar cada par que extraigo con los demás y ver si existe su simétrico. Muchas gracias, y  espero su ayuda!

Estos son los códigos:
index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Relaciones Binarias</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-es.js"></script>
  <style>
    .top-buffer {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container ">
    <div class="row-fluid top-buffer">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
        <form id="miform" method="post" name="miform" action="guarda.php">


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cantidad de elementos:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cantidad"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


          <table id="tblprod" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Par #</th>
                <th>Elementos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <input class="form-control validate[required]" name="elemento1[]" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <input class="form-control validate[required]" name="elemento2[]" />
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button id="btnadd" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Nuevo</button>
          <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var count = 1;
      jQuery("#miform").validationEngine({
        promptPosition: "centerRight:0,-5"
      });

      $(document).on("click", "#btnadd", function(event) {
        count++;
        $('#tblprod tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td><div class="form-group col-lg-4"><input class="form-control validate[required]" name=" elemento1[]" /></div><div class="form-group col-lg-4"><input class="form-control validate[required]" name="elemento2[]" /></div></td></tr>');
        event.preventDefault();

      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

guarda.php

```
<?php

$reflexivo = 0;
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
echo "Pares:";echo "<br>";
foreach (array_keys($_POST['elemento1']) as $key) {
  $elemento1 = $_POST['elemento1'][$key];
  $elemento2 = $_POST['elemento2'][$key];


  echo "($elemento1".","."$elemento2".")&nbsp;";
 
   if ($elemento1 == $elemento2) {
    $reflexivo += 1;
  }
 
}
 

echo "<br>";
 if ($reflexivo == $cantidad) {
    echo "es reflexivo";
 }
 else {
    echo "no es reflexivo";
 }
 echo "<br>";
 
  
 echo "<br>";


?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para comparar cada elemento con el resto, por cada elemento debes recorrer el array nuevamente para compararlo con todos los otros...